# django metismenu nav active on page change

Tags: jquery, django, drop-down-menu, nav

I want to change the side menu highlighted field based on what page I am on. I've been working on this all day and cannot seem to solve the issue.

HTML:

```
<!--- Start Side Navigation --->
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                 {% if sma.active == True %}
                      <span>
                          <img alt="image" class="img-circle" height="80" width="80" src="{{ sma.profile_picture_object.thumbnail_url }}" />
                      </span>
                 {% endif %}
                     <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
                         <span class="clear">
                             <span class="text-muted text-xs block">
                                 <img src="small.png"> 
                             </span>
                         </span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="active">
                  <a href="{% url 'website:dashboard' %}">
                      <i class="fa fa-linode"></i>
                          <span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                          <span class="nav-label">Accounts</span>
                              <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                      <li class="">
                          <a href="{% url 'website:accounts_detail' sma.id %}">Current Account</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:accounts_edit' %}">Edit Account
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:accounts_list'%}">Switch Account
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:accounts_add' %}">Add Account
                          </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>
                          <span class="nav-label">Ambassadors</span>
                              <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:ambassadors_list_active' %}">Search
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:ambassadors_list_requested' %}">Requested
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="{% url 'website:ambassadors_list_authorized' %}">Authorized
                          </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location;
            var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
                return this.href === url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) === 0;
            }).addClass('active');
            $(element.parents()).each(function() {
                if (this.className.indexOf('collapse') !== -1) {
                    $(this).addClass('in');
                }
            });
            element = element.parent().parent().parent();
            if (element.is('li')) {
                element.addClass('active');
            }
            $(function () {
                $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

This currently only works for the accounts page and only un-collapses the dropdown. I cannot seem to figure out how to highlight/active the correct li class. I also tried using django templates, however most of the urls are very similar to the accounts one where the url path is /accounts/userID/.

I would appreciate any help, I've been working on this for a few hours. I feel like I made progress with the last edits.

EDIT:

It also doesnt remove the active class from the dashboard li

Comment: Are you trying to tell which dropdown should be open on page load?

Comment: Yeah thats what I want. So If the user presses accounts edit, it loads the accounts edit page and shows the dropdown state as accounts-> edit

Answer (score 0):

A pure django solution using django template tags is to take advantage of request.resolver_match.

So for each item that you want highlighted add this:

```
    <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "website:accounts_detail" %}active{% endif %}" />
```